# Name for sorting algorithm "while not sorted, swap the FIRST unordered pair"

Tags: terminology, sorting

A typical bubble sort steps through all pair indices until it reaches the end of the list, then starts a new pass.

For a toy problem, we have a variant that just performs the first available swap in each iteration and repeats until sorted. It does not continue from the position of the last swap.

Is there a standard name for this sort? It seems so trivial that it must have a name, but we were surprised not to find it on any obvious lists. It's just like, a raw comparison sort.

### Bubble

```
4, 3, 2, 1
3, 4, 2, 1
3, 2, 4, 1
3, 2, 1, 4 <- Different
2, 3, 1, 4
2, 1, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4
```

### Variant

```
4, 3, 2, 1
3, 4, 2, 1
3, 2, 4, 1
2, 3, 4, 1 <- Different
2, 3, 1, 4
2, 1, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4
```

**Don't worry, this is not meant to be a good sorting algorithm, just for a fun thing.**

Comment: Feel like maybe somebody's gonna say this is close enough to just call a bubble sort? It does produce different intermediate states, though.

Comment: There are many more ideas than there are standard "names".  The great thing about language is that we can describe our ideas even if they don't have a "name".  What's the motivation for asking for a "name"?  What would you do with an answer?  If your goal is to use the "name" to do something, perhaps it would be better to ask how to do that something; then people could help you with that even if there isn't a standard "name".

Comment: @D.W. Our question was asked competently, all due respect but we don't need the premise questioned. That's one of the more annoying habits of StackExchange sites. This algorithm is being used in a pen-and-paper maths-puzzle, and we're just interested in a name because it might inspire a name for the puzzle, and because we were a little surprised to find that it wasn't in the standard lists of sorting algorithms, despite being essentially the simplest form of comparison sort imaginable.

Comment: My first response was this is a variant of insertion sort, definitely not bubble sort. I neglected to consider the fact that it may sweep repeatedly from the left to find the leftmost inversion, making this an $O(n^3)$ sort. I think you are safe to christen this sort however you like.

Answer (score 2):

In more detail, this variant of bubble sort finds the leftmost pair of adjacent items that are in the wrong order. Then it swaps those two items. This operation of "find and swap" is repeated until the given list is sorted. In other words, this variant of bubble sort swaps the items in the leftmost [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) of the given list repeatedly until the given list is sorted. (Note the two items in the leftmost inversion must be adjacent).

There is no standard or popular name for this variant of bubble sort, or so I believe.

I would call it **left-bubble sort**, a name that captures its conceptual intention. We could also have **right-bubble sort**, which swaps the items in the rightmost inversion repeatedly until sorted. We could also have **random-bubble sort**, which swaps two randomly-selected adjacent items that are in the wrong order repeatedly until sorted. If we do not even require the two items to be adjacent, we can have **random-swap sort**. Depending on how the inversion is selected randomly, "random-swap sort" can become bogo-sort<sub>opt</sub>, bozo-sort<sub>opt</sub>, and bozo-sort<sup>+</sup><sub>opt</sub> that  appear in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-72914-3_17).

The above description of left-bubble sort does not specify how to find the leftmost inversion in each iteration. A naive implementation may always comparing the first two items, then the next two items and so on until it finds the first inversion or stops. We can observe that the initial part of the list during the left-bubble sort is sorted. Since there cannot be any inversion in the initial part of the list, we can optimize the implementation by just comparing the item that was just moved to the left with the item right before it without comparing the initial adjacent items.

Whether we use the naive implementation or the optimized implementation above, left-bubble sort behaves exactly the same as the simplest insertion sort, in terms of the states the given list goes through until sorted. The simplest insert sort here corresponds to the first pseudocode at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), which is implemented in *Programming Pearls* (2000) by Jon Bentley.

Here is an illustration of the states produced by left-bubble sort.

```
4, 3, 2, 1    <- 4 is considered inserted into the expected place.
3, 4, 2, 1    <- 3 is inserted into the expected place
3, 2, 4, 1
2, 3, 4, 1    <- 2 is inserted into the expected place
2, 3, 1, 4
2, 1, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4    <- 1 is inserted into the expected place
```

In particular, left-bubble sort builds the final sorted array (or list) one item at a time, which is the defining characteristic of "insertion sort" according to [that Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). We can thus treat (the optimized version of) left-bubble sort as another name for the simplest insertion sort.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but don't really feel that this is a correct answer. The relation to insertion sort is interesting (though we already knew it) but it's still a variant, so doesn't really get us any closer than bubble sort. The algorithm specifically needs to be defined in terms of swaps, and insertion sort is not.

Comment: It may well be that it just doesn't have a name. That just seems a little surprising given that "while the list is not sorted, swap the first unordered pair" is essentially the simplest comparison sort imaginable. You'd think that would have a name, even if it's just "naive sort" or something. It seems odd that bubble-variants like cocktail have a name, but nobody has ever named this.

Comment: Please take a look at the pseudocode for the insertion sort at Wikipedia. It is also defined in terms of swap.

Comment: This variant of bubble sort produces exactly the same states of the array (or list) in exactly the same order as the insertion sort. If that is not convincing enough, what else could be more convincing?

Comment: If I do give this variant of bubble sort a new name and then, how would people feel as this variant produces exactly the same states in exactly the same order as the standard insertion sort? Most of the people, I believe, will treat it just as a different way to describe the standard insertion sort.

Comment: Hmm, we''ll give it to you because you make a good case from the equivalence, although it's not particularly useful for us as insertion sort conceptually describes a different way of understanding the process. We really wanted something that communicates the swap-the-first-one idea of the algorithm. It seems like the name we're looking for just doesn't exist, so your answer is as close as we'll get.

Comment: Only some implementations of insertion sort give the right intermediate states. As implied by the name, typical implementations move the item multiple positions in one step. A GOOD answer would be the name of a sort that unambiguously produces the intermediate states with the adjacent swaps. For that reason, it is NOT equivalent to insertion sort, and would be reasonable for it to have its own name.

Comment: I would agree that pseudocode for insertion sort can be called the slow insertion sort.

Comment: Yeah that's a reasonable name from that angle, although the fact that it's not really conceptually doing insertion makes it awkward. It's describing a simpler sort in relation to a more complex one, which seems backward.

Comment: On reflection, we've unaccepted this answer. Sorry. We accepted it because we were trying to be nice and you put effort in to helping us, but ultimately it doesn't quite answer the question, and it's bad for the ecosystem if we mark it as right when it isn't. Nothing personal, thanks for trying.

Comment: What about my updated answer? There is no hurry to accept my answer. We can wait for a few more days or a few more weeks or even months lest an existing popular name comes up in a new answer.